# java-Printing Reversed Triangle containing numbers 9-0

Tags: java

Hello guys i need your help here is my code

```
public class act_numTria {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int z = 9;
    for(int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
      for(int y = 4; y >= x; y--) {
        System.out.print(z);
        z--;
      }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

the output is:

```
9876
543
21
0
```

but it should be like this

```
6789
345
12
0
```

Comment: Using z as a counter like this is never going to work (unless you get some string manipulation involved). Can you calculate the minimum and maximum values you expect on each row? From that point it should be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to involve any string operations, you can do this...

```
public class act_numTria {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int z = 9;
      for(int x=1;x<=4;x++){
         for(int y=4;y>=x;y--){
            System.out.print(z-y+1);
         }
         z = z - (4 - x);
         System.out.print("\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you this is better :) i know that my instructor will be suspicious if i use the first one haha thank you thank you :D

Comment: Just make sure that you get the logic, don't just copy it for your homework... Glad to have helped!

Comment: oh yes ofcourse thats what i doing right now hehe i'm need to improve my logical thinking and analization newbie here haha.. :) thank you by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified code of yours .. you just need to accumulate your digits and then reverse it:

```
 public class act_numTria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int z = 9;
        for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int y = 4; y >= x; y--) {
                sb.append(z--);
            }
            System.out.print(sb.reverse().toString() + "\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is another solution to your problem:

```
public class act_numTria {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int start = 6;
            int diff = 3;
            for (int z = start; diff>=0; z=start) {
                for(int i=z;i<=start+diff;i++) {
                    System.out.print(i);
                }
                System.out.println();
                start-=diff;
                diff--;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I glad that is helped you. kindly select best one as answer.